# Can we find the coefficient of determination, $R^2$, from an estimated regression equation?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, r-squared

Assume we have a regression equation where $\hat y = 15 + 25.5 x_1 - 5 x_2 + 6 x_3$

Using these beta values, how would you go about finding a coefficient of determination?

Comment: Please check the definition of the [$R^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination). It states clearly you need the original data $y$ as well as the estimated data $\hat{y}$.

Comment: The question here has a flawed premise but it still seems to me to be a useful and legitimate question.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: You don't *solve* anything here. Please fix the title when you edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find the coefficient of determination $R^2$ simply from the regression coefficients $\beta_0,\ldots,\beta_3$. You also need the data $\{x_1,x_2,x_3;y\}$ you used to find the regression function. Check the Wikipedia page for the definition of $R^2$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination.

Comment: You actually need far less than the original data in order to compute $R^2$.  There are several standard, well-known formulas for it in terms of centered second moments of the variables.

Comment: You are right of course :) Given the nature of the question, I did not want to go intro the details on what you need to know in order to compute $R^2$. I simply assumed that the data is known, since this is the most intuitive way of computing $R^2$.